# Each function after load, or the other way around?

Tags: jquery, load, position, each

I could just test this, but because internet speeds are so fast my images are loaded so quickly I am not sure that this works or not.

I want to write a function that gets each image's width and repositions the image after it has been loaded. I was thinking something like this, but I am not sure whether this will work?

```
$("#social-media li a > img").each(function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        w1 = $this.parent().width() / 2,
        w2 = $this.width() / 2,
        w3 = w1 - w2;

    $this.load(function () {
        $this.css("left", w3);
    });
});
```

Comment: Sorry, couldn't resist :P : http://i.qkme.me/3tznqu.jpg

Comment: @Sunyatasattva It's true!

Comment: Check out [fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/), that lets you also throttle your bandwidth!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, please don't use the [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) method for the event triggering, it has been deprecated in jQuery 1.8 because of the confusion with the AJAX method of the same name. Use the [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method instead.

Second, as mentioned in the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/):

> ### Caveats of the load event when used with images
>
> A common challenge developers attempt to solve using the `.load()` shortcut is to execute a function when an image (or collection of images) have completely loaded. There are several known caveats with this that should be noted. These are:
>
> - It doesn't work consistently nor reliably cross-browser.
> - It doesn't fire correctly in WebKit if the image src is set to the same src as before
> - It doesn't correctly bubble up the DOM tree
> - Can cease to fire for images that already live in the browser's cache

That said, I think the [**imagesLoaded plugin**](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded) by David DeSandro might address those issues and work for what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Normally I'm not a real fan of plugins but this works flawlessly, so I'll use it. Thanks!

Comment: Me neither! I prefer doing it with my own hands, even if it means to reinvent the wheel sometimes. But David DeSandro is good, hands down.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate after window load, then you don't need to wait till image load 
Try this code

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $("#social-media li a > img").each(function() {
        var $this = $(this),
                w1 = $this.parent().width() / 2,
                w2 = $this.width() / 2,
                w3 = w1 - w2;

        $this.css("left", w3);
    });
});
```

Comment: I want to execute as soon as the images are loaded, not when the whole window has loaded.